# Guid is all 0's (zeros)?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, guid

I'm testing out some WCF services that send objects with Guids back and forth. In my web app test code, I'm doing the following:

```
var responseObject = proxy.CallService(new RequestObject
{
    Data = "misc. data",
    Guid = new Guid()
});
```

For some reason, the call to **new Guid()** is generating Guids with all 0's (zeros) like this:

`00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`

What could be causing this?

Comment: Overlapping: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7972658/60761

Comment: +1 because I've used this question to steal a blank guid a dozen times :)

Answer (score 522, accepted):

Use the static method [`Guid.NewGuid()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) instead of calling the default constructor.

```
var responseObject = proxy.CallService(new RequestObject
{
    Data = "misc. data",
    Guid = Guid.NewGuid()
});
```

Comment: +1 for the correct answer as well as a link to the proper documentation.

Answer (score 122):

Lessons to learn from this:

1) Guid is a value type, not a reference type.

2) Calling the default constructor `new S()` on any value type always gives you back the all-zero form of that value type, whatever it is.  It is logically the same as `default(S)`.

Comment: Does it compile into the same IL as `default(S)` or are there any subtleties I'm missing?

Comment: @configurator: It does. In fact, the compiler's internal representation of "default(S)" and "new S()" are the same; we do not distinguish them internally, which has led to some unfortunate bugs over the years because they are in fact not *quite* identical. For example, `const int x = new int();` is not supposed to be legal according to the spec, but `const int x = default(int);` is; we allow both.

Comment: @configurator - if you're interested in related corner cases, perhaps http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/12/10/value-types-and-parameterless-constructors.aspx would also be of interest.

Answer (score 60):

Try this instead:

```
var responseObject = proxy.CallService(new RequestObject
{
    Data = "misc. data",
    Guid = new Guid.NewGuid()
});
```

This will generate a 'real' Guid value.  When you new a reference type, it will give you the default value (which in this case, is all zeroes for a Guid).

When you create a new Guid, it will initialize it to all zeroes, which is the default value for Guid.  It's basically the same as creating a "new" int (which is a value type but you can do this anyways):

```
Guid g1;                    // g1 is 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Guid g2 = new Guid();       // g2 is 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Guid g3 = default(Guid);    // g3 is 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Guid g4 = Guid.NewGuid();   // g4 is not all zeroes
```

Compare this to doing the same thing with an int:

```
int i1;                     // i1 is 0
int i2 = new int();         // i2 is 0
int i3 = default(int);      // i3 is 0
```

Comment: `g1` will only compile as field and not as local variable. Also the indices in your comment column don't match up with the same line of the code

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Thanks, fixed the comments.  FYI, the g1 line does actually compile...

Comment: It will compile as is, but it has no defined value. If you add code that reads it (before writing to it) it will not compile anymore.

Comment: Right, good point, you will get an error if you use an uninitialized variable, so the value cannot be used.

Comment: down-voted because the line "Guid = Guid.NewGuid();" may confuse newer developers. Consider editing to something like "Guid someGuid = Guid.NewGuid();"

like the g2 line ;)

Comment: @daviesdoesit that line was meant to replace the line from the question (where they are setting the property named "Guid").  I added the sample code which should make it clearer

Comment: To be more clear, in your sample code, you are using GUID like a type.
 public static void Main()
 {
  Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
  // Guid = Guid.NewGuid(); // this fails: "Guid" is a type but is used like a variable.
  Guid someGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
  Console.WriteLine(someGuid ); // yields a usable Guid as expected.

 }

Comment: Additionally, the line with g1 may compile, but does not (as your comment on the same line may suggest) yield a blank Guid of all zeroes;  As you noted (and in above answers) the Guid is a reference type and must be instantiated, hence the Guid.NewGuid() requirement.  If you tried to use g1 prior to assigning it a value it would error out.  In a new dotnetfiddle try the following:  
  Guid g1;
  Console.WriteLine(g1); // Use of unassigned local variable

Comment: There's a 'new' too many in 'Guid = *new* Guid.NewGuid()', the 4th line of the first example. It must have wound up in there in an edit, because I can't believe it took 8 years for someone to notice that. And I think there's something wrong with the next paragraph, "when you 'new' a reference type, it will give you the default value". Guid is a value type.

Answer (score 33):

Try doing:

```
Guid foo = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Comment: Reason for downvote: "Guid" is a type but is used like a variable.

Answer (score 19):

Can't tell you how many times this has caught. me.

```
Guid myGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Answer (score 12):

In the spirit of being complete, the answers that instruct you to use `Guid.NewGuid()` are correct.

In addressing your subsequent edit, you'll need to post the code for your `RequestObject` class. I'm suspecting that your guid property is not marked as a `DataMember`, and thus is not being serialized over the wire. Since `default(Guid)` is the same as `new Guid()` (i.e. all `0`'s), this would explain the behavior you're seeing.