# how do i generate a nullable guid with linq to sql

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, orm

I have a (legacy) table with two guid fields. The second guid field can be null, but I want to auto-generate a non-dupe guid on insert using linq to sql. I have auto-sync set to "OnInsert" and Auto Generate Value set to True. But for some reason, it is not autogenerating/inserting guid values when the records are being put in the DB. I guess I could loop generating guids until I find one that is not in the DB and then add it in, but that does not seem very elegant. I am sure there is a better way to do this using linq to sql. Any suggestions on how to do this? Is it not making the guid because the nullable property is set to T?

[image]

I had a similar issue before, but learned how to change the properties of the ID field so that linq to sql could add the guid [How do i prevent Linq from adding a GUID so that SQL server can do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741913/how-do-i-prevent-linq-from-adding-a-guid-so-that-sql-server-can-do-it) I can't use that solution here because the guid in this case is nullable and is not the PK, so I can't change the properties the way I did in the linked question.

Comment: *"I guess I could loop generating guids until I find one that is not in the DB..."* If you use `Guid.NewGuid()` to generate GUIDs, you should never generate two that are identical.  If that happens, you will have just beaten absolutely incredible odds.  It is safe to assume that `Guid.NewGuid()` will return a GUID that nobody on the planet has ever generated before.

Comment: @cdhowie you should make that an answer so i can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess I could loop generating guids until I find one that is not in the DB...

If you use `Guid.NewGuid()` to generate GUIDs, you should never generate two that are identical. If that happens, you will have just beaten absolutely incredible odds. It is safe to assume that `Guid.NewGuid()` will return a GUID that nobody on the planet has ever generated before.